# WPF ResourceDictionary context menu - menu item visibility property update from other class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I got a ResourceDictionary in my WPF project. The entire project is meant to be running in background. In ResourceDictionary there is a context menu, code is here;

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Commands="clr-namespace:_365Drive.Office365.NotificationManager"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_365Drive.Office365.NotificationManager">

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.259" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu" Name="contextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Sign in" Command="{Binding ShowAuthForm}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Prompt MFA now" Name="MFA"  Command="{Binding ClearMFACacheCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding MFAVisibility}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sign out" Command="{Binding SignOutApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Update Drive Mappings" Command="{Binding RefreshSettingsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitApplicationCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The code behind of it is as follows (Snippet of code only)

```
public class NotifyIconViewModel
{
    private Visibility visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility MFAVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return ((1) == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible);
        }
        set
        {
            visibility = value;
        }
    }
}
```

There is other code in the code behind but that is irrelevant for this question.

I want to update the above property value from other class in the same project but I am not sure how can I get the instance of that class which is bound with the contextMenu.

And if I do try to set the MenuItem Visibility using code like below, it doesnt work;

```
public static void DisableMFAMenuitem()
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu ctxMenu = (System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("SysTrayMenu");
    System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection items = ctxMenu.Items;
    System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem itemtobeRemoved = null;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem))
        {
            // do your work with the item 
            if (((System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem)item).Name == "MFA")
            {
                ((System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem)item).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // OR WHATEVER really
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I am doing some small mistake in understanding, can anyone help here please?

Comment: it will work only if you have opened context menu or any instance of this context menu .
where are you creating this context menu instance and you have to bind its visibility property when you assign datacontext to this context menu

Comment: What is this: `(1) == null`?

Comment: (1) == null is just dummy. It will be replaced with actual logic later. Lets not worry about that, if thats true, the menu should be visible. Sorry for not mentioning its  dummy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here, but from the first glimpse my guess would be that the troublemaker is the [`x:Shared="False"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute set on your resource, which means that each `FindResource("SysTrayMenu")` call will yield a new `ContextMenu` instance (so you're not modifying any pre-existing instance).

Comment: @Grx70, you are a hero :) That did the trick. I cant mark it as answer as its a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly `Visibility` in your `ViewModel` is not really `MvvM` it would be safer to just use `Boolean`. Secondly if you put a handler on a click for your `ContextMenu` you should check it's `DataContext` there you should have the instance of the class you want to change the property on.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Grx70 above helped.

> I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here, but from
>   the first glimpse my guess would be that the troublemaker is the
>   x:Shared="False" attribute set on your resource, which means that each
>   FindResource("SysTrayMenu") call will yield a new ContextMenu instance
>   (so you're not modifying any pre-existing instance).